# Android: How do I download a file from a dynamic url webview

Tags: android, webview

In my app I am using a webview to navigate through to a site, automatically fill in a web form using javascript then submit to obtain a link to a CSV export file. 
The link looks like this: XYZ.com/TEST/index/getexport?id=130.

I'd like to download the file this URL points to, then when complete read it into a local database but I'm having trouble downloading the linked file.

If I simply try to open the URL in webview I get an error from the webpage telling me no such file exists.

If I use the Download Manager to download it myself, the source code is downloaded as an html file, not the associated .csv file.

I can open the url with an ACTION_VIEW intent and a browser (chrome) downloads the correct file, but this way I have no notification of when the download completes.

Any ideas of how to download my .CSV file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To download a file from webview use this :

```
mWebView.setDownloadListener(new DownloadListener(){ 
    public void onDownloadStart(String url, String userAgent, String contentDisposition, String mimetype, long contentLength){ 
        Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW); 
        i.setData(Uri.parse(url));
        startActivity(i); 
    } 
});
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Where to put it, and what other things need to be defined for WebView Settings?

Answer (score 0):

You could resort to manually downloading the file from the url using an AsyncTask.

Here id the background part:

```
@Override
protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
    String filename = "inputAFileName";

    HttpURLConnection c;
    try {
        URL url = new URL("http://someurl/" + filename);
        c = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        c.setRequestMethod("GET");
        c.setDoOutput(true);
        c.connect();
    } catch (IOException e1) {
        return e1.getMessage();
    }

    File myFilesDir = new File(Environment
            .getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()
            + "/Download");

    File file = new File(myFilesDir, filename);

    if (file.exists()) {
        file.delete();
    }

    if ((myFilesDir.mkdirs() || myFilesDir.isDirectory())) {
        try {
            InputStream is = c.getInputStream();
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(myFilesDir
                    + "/" + filename);

            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            int len1 = 0;
            while ((len1 = is.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                fos.write(buffer, 0, len1);
            }
            fos.close();
            is.close();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            return e.getMessage();
        }

        if (file.exists()) {
            return "File downloaded!";
        } else {
             Log.e(TAG, "file not found");
        }
    } else {
        Log.e(TAG, "unable to create folder");
    }
}
```

Perhaps it would make sense to refactor it so that the file is returned. Then you get the file as an argument in onPostExecute as soon as the download is complete.

Comment: I've looked into this approach, but my download URL does not contain a filename.

Comment: I would think that it would still work if issuing GET on the url results in a file. Of course you would have to change the code accordingly, creating a name for the file so that it can be created on the phone.

Comment: Just tried this, it downloads html source code and not the file I'm after. How is this any different to what the native browser is doing?

Comment: and if you use the same address in a browser you get the csv? it looks like the header of the response is incorrect...

Comment: Yeah - if I throw it over to Android's Chrome with ACTION.VIEW, or even copy/paste into a PC browser the correct download triggers. I have no control over the web page's contents which makes things a little trickier...