# Android webview: download files like browsers do

Tags: android, webview, download, permissions, dynamic-links

I'm working on an Android app with a webview pointing to a dynamic website by another team.
When i download a file (mostly **dynamically redirected** PDF and ZIP) **all i get is a file in the downloads folder containing some HTML code with a message like "user not allowed to read the file"**, no matter how i implement the download, i tried:

1. DownloadManager
2. Intent (letting an external browser to manage the download)
3. "by hand" (AsyncTask and httpconnection...)

all with the same results.

**Navigating with normal browsers downloads work fine, both on desktop PC, android and iOS devices**.

**Why webview shouldn't have access to files?**

May be a session issue? http port?
I really need some ideas...
Another tip: when downloading twice a file from the same link, the link will redirect to the same file but resulting in two different filenames...

**EDIT**: Instead of pointing the webView to the web-app, i tried to point to a common webpage with a link-redirect to download another file, well, simply it works.

Here are the `webview.setDownloadListener - onDownloadStart()` parameters:

```
 userAgent=Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 4.4.2; Nexus 7 Build/KOT49H) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Chrome/30.0.0.0 Safari/537.36

 contentDisposition=attachment;
 filename=correct_filename.pdf,      
 url=http://www.xxx.xx/site/downloadfile.wplus?REDIRECTFILE=D-507497120&ID_COUNTOBJ=ce_5_home&TYPEOBJ=CExFILE&LN=2

 mimeType=application/octet-stream
```

Here's some code

```
    wv.getSettings().setSupportMultipleWindows(true);
    wv.getSettings().setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
    wv.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);
    wv.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    wv.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    wv.getSettings().setDisplayZoomControls(false);
    wv.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
    wv.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
    wv.setDownloadListener(new DownloadListener() {
        @Override           
        public void onDownloadStart(String url, String userAgent, String contentDisposition, String mimetype, long contentLength){ 
            DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(Uri.parse(url));

            request.setDescription("Download file...");
            request.setTitle(URLUtil.guessFileName(url, contentDisposition, mimetype));
            request.allowScanningByMediaScanner();
            request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED); //Notify client once download is completed!
            request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS, URLUtil.guessFileName(url, contentDisposition, mimetype));
            DownloadManager dm = (DownloadManager) getSystemService(DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
            dm.enqueue(request);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Downloading File", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } 
    }
```

**EDIT II**
Here's the code i'm using when trying to download files "by hand":

onDownloadStart() is where i call downloadFileAsync():

```
        public void onDownloadStart(String url, String userAgent, String contentDisposition, String mimeType, long contentLength) {
            String fileName;
            try {
                fileName = URLUtil.guessFileName(url, contentDisposition, mimeType);
                downloadFileAsync(url, fileName);
            }catch (Exception e){

            }
        }
```

and this is the AsyncTask:

```
private void downloadFileAsync(String url, String filename){

    new AsyncTask<String, Void, String>() {
        String SDCard;

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            try {
                URL url = new URL(params[0]);
                HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
                urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
                urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);
                urlConnection.connect();
                int lengthOfFile = urlConnection.getContentLength();
                //SDCard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + File.separator + "downloads";
                SDCard = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS)+"";
                int k = 0;
                boolean file_exists;
                String finalValue = params[1];
                do {
                    if (k > 0) {
                        if (params[1].length() > 0) {
                            String s = params[1].substring(0, params[1].lastIndexOf("."));
                            String extension = params[1].replace(s, "");

                            finalValue = s + "(" + k + ")" + extension;
                        } else {
                            String fileName = params[0].substring(params[0].lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
                            String s = fileName.substring(0, fileName.lastIndexOf("."));
                            String extension = fileName.replace(s, "");
                            finalValue = s + "(" + k + ")" + extension;
                        }
                    }
                    File fileIn = new File(SDCard, finalValue);
                    file_exists = fileIn.exists();
                    k++;
                } while (file_exists);

                File file = new File(SDCard, finalValue);
                FileOutputStream fileOutput = null;
                fileOutput = new FileOutputStream(file, true);
                InputStream inputStream = null;
                inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();
                byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
                int count;
                long total = 0;
                while ((count = inputStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                    total += count;
                    //publishProgress(""+(int)((total*100)/lengthOfFile));
                    fileOutput.write(buffer, 0, count);
                }
                fileOutput.flush();
                fileOutput.close();
                inputStream.close();
            } catch (MalformedURLException e){
            } catch (ProtocolException e){
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e){
            } catch (IOException e){
            } catch (Exception e){
            }
            return params[1];
        }
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(final String result) {

        }

    }.execute(url, filename);
}
```

taken from [How to download a PDF from a dynamic URL in a webview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31825957/how-to-download-pdf-from-dynamic-url-in-android-webview)

Thanx

Comment: you seem to be downloading files in external storage.  make sure you have the permission (<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />) in your manifest. see if that works

Comment: @Tasos of course i have set it, anyway thanx.

Comment: ok, you can always emded crosswalk which has the same api's like chrome browser and more  to make things easy.  you only need to add (<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />)  and it will download files, no problem.  https://crosswalk-project.org/  -- give it a test  -- https://github.com/dougdiego/CrosswalkDemo -- in gradle use the latest build tool, SDK and crosswalk version (15.44.384.12)

Comment: @Tasos ok, thanx, but i won't start over learning something completely new to me, i just would like to understand why my app cannot download those files, while is perfectly able to download every other file from every other websites. What can cause a "firewall" that doesn't allow my app to download these dynamic files?

Comment: well you have to check the firewalls logs to see why. maybe its a setting on there you need to change.

Comment: @Tasos i cannot access the server, the web-app is by another team i'm not in relation with... Anyway, is there somthing i can try? Can i try to use the same http port of other browsers to "look like" them?

Comment: 'by hand" (AsyncTask and httpconnection...)

all with the same results.'. That is hard to believe. Then why would you save the content to the downloads folder?

Comment: @greenapps just tested it again, downloadFileAsync() code taken here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31825957/how-to-download-pdf-from-dynamic-url-in-android-webview, same result: a file correctly named but containing only a bunch of html saying "not allowed". All seems to be ok, but the result is an unespected one, i'd like to understand why.

Comment: A browsers sends a bunch of headers and identifies itself as a well know browser. You are of course not sending all those headers.

Comment: @greenapps this could be the point, can you explain, please?

Comment: What should i explain? I just told that it could be missing headers.

Comment: @greenapps how can i add headers, can you show me a bunch of code or a link for that? thank you!

Comment: Then do you know already which headers you have to add? Further you did not post your asynctask code so how would i know where they had to be added?

Comment: @greenapps in a previous comment i added a link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31825957/how-to-download-pdf-from-dynamic-url-in-android-webview where i found that code - downloadFileAsync()... i'm gonna editing my question to add that code...

Comment: `do you know already which headers you have to add?`

Comment: @greenapps no i don't, i just used the code i found here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31825957/how-to-download-pdf-from-dynamic-url-in-android-webview. Where should i look for?

Comment: There is a world of info on this site for setting headers. Did you google for urlConnection.setRequestHeader ? `Where should i look for?` ??? What do you mean? But if you do not know which headers you wanna add all makes little sense.

Comment: @greenapps i mean: how to know which headers i have to add? Please, consider this: i'm "translating" an existing iOS app, where download works itself, no need to add any kind of code for it! I didn't expect i had to write a download manager myself :O I don't know anything about  connection-request-headers and whatever! Now you know.

Comment: Well i do not know which headers you have to set. Sorry. You have to find out your self.

Comment: @greenapps thanx alot

Answer (score 63, accepted):

Finally i decided to look for the
[DownloadHandler from the Android Stock Browser code](https://github.com/android/platform_packages_apps_browser/blob/master/src/com/android/browser/DownloadHandler.java).
The only noticeable lack in my code was **cookie** (!!!).

Here's my final working version (DownloadManager method):

```
    wv.setDownloadListener(new DownloadListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDownloadStart(String url, String userAgent, String contentDisposition, String mimeType, long contentLength) {
            DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(Uri.parse(url));

            request.setMimeType(mimeType);
            //------------------------COOKIE!!------------------------
            String cookies = CookieManager.getInstance().getCookie(url);
            request.addRequestHeader("cookie", cookies);
            //------------------------COOKIE!!------------------------
            request.addRequestHeader("User-Agent", userAgent);
            request.setDescription("Downloading file...");
            request.setTitle(URLUtil.guessFileName(url, contentDisposition, mimeType));
            request.allowScanningByMediaScanner();
            request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED);
            request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS, URLUtil.guessFileName(url, contentDisposition, mimeType));
            DownloadManager dm = (DownloadManager) getSystemService(DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
            dm.enqueue(request);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Downloading File", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
```

Comment: Thank you for this! This is what I was missing too. My webview was trying to download a PDF from a dynamic (auto-generated link).

Comment: @j.c Kindly answer below question I have tried many things but nothing helped!
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43140708/file-download-from-webview-is-not-working-in-android-i-am-trying-this-way

Comment: Hi you forgot to mention <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" /> in manifest file.

Comment: how to save in custom specific folder like:
root/My Folder/File.ext

Comment: the cookie line is throwing nullpointerexception but after commenting that the code is working.

Answer (score 6):

With this option I managed to download complete files, the download worked with other options but the documents appeared empty, especially when a session is being used.

Add below lines to `AndroidManifest.xml`

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

Add DownloadListener to your WebView

Try this code

```
wv.setDownloadListener(new DownloadListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDownloadStart(final String url, final String userAgent, String contentDisposition, String mimetype, long contentLength) {
        //Checking runtime permission for devices above Marshmallow.
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            if (checkSelfPermission(android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
                    == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                Log.v(TAG, "Permission is granted");
                downloadDialog(url, userAgent, contentDisposition, mimetype);

            } else {

                Log.v(TAG, "Permission is revoked");
                //requesting permissions.
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(PortalActivity.this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, 1);

            }
        } else {
            //Code for devices below API 23 or Marshmallow
            Log.v(TAG, "Permission is granted");
            downloadDialog(url, userAgent, contentDisposition, mimetype);

        }
    }
});

//downloadDialog Method

public void downloadDialog(final String url, final String userAgent, String contentDisposition, String mimetype) {
    //getting filename from url.
    final String filename = URLUtil.guessFileName(url, contentDisposition, mimetype);
    //alertdialog
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

    //title of alertdialog
    builder.setTitle(R.string.download_title);
    //message of alertdialog
    builder.setMessage(getString(R.string.download_file) + ' ' + filename);
    //if Yes button clicks.

    builder.setPositiveButton(getString(R.string.yes), new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            //DownloadManager.Request created with url.
            DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(Uri.parse(url));
            //cookie
            String cookie = CookieManager.getInstance().getCookie(url);
            //Add cookie and User-Agent to request
            request.addRequestHeader("Cookie", cookie);
            request.addRequestHeader("User-Agent", userAgent);
            //file scanned by MediaScannar
            request.allowScanningByMediaScanner();
            //Download is visible and its progress, after completion too.
            request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED);
            //DownloadManager created
            DownloadManager downloadManager = (DownloadManager) getSystemService(DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
            //Saving files in Download folder
            request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS, filename);
            //download enqued
            downloadManager.enqueue(request);
        }
    });
    builder.setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            //cancel the dialog if Cancel clicks
            dialog.cancel();
            mWebView.goBack();
        }

    });
    //alertdialog shows.
    builder.show();

}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
wv.setDownloadListener(new DownloadListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDownloadStart(String url, String userAgent, String 
    contentDisposition, String mimeType, long contentLength) {
        DownloadManager.Request request = new 
    DownloadManager.Request(Uri.parse(url));

        request.setMimeType(mimeType);
        //------------------------COOKIE!!------------------------
        String cookies = CookieManager.getInstance().getCookie(url);
        request.addRequestHeader("cookie", cookies);
        //------------------------COOKIE!!------------------------
        request.addRequestHeader("User-Agent", userAgent);
        request.setDescription("Downloading file...");
        request.setTitle(URLUtil.guessFileName(url, contentDisposition, mimeType));
        request.allowScanningByMediaScanner();
        request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED);
        request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS, URLUtil.guessFileName(url, contentDisposition, mimeType));
        DownloadManager dm = (DownloadManager) getSystemService(DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
        dm.enqueue(request);
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Downloading File", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
});
```

thanks j.c for your answer
you missed **);** at end of code..

Answer (score 1):

also you can use :

```
mWebView.setDownloadListener(new DownloadListener() {
public void onDownloadStart(String url, String userAgent,
            String contentDisposition, String mimetype,
            long contentLength) {
    Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    i.setData(Uri.parse(url));
    startActivity(i);
}});
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to note - you also should add "Referer" request header - without it some sites simply will not let you to download files.