# File Download from Webview is not working in android, I am trying this way,

Tags: android, webview, android-download-manager

Below is my Code for implementing a webview which opens a link which have tabular information on date selection 
and having three buttons in the bottom for downloading pdf, xls and doc file 
download works well in browser but in webview download is not happening!

```
public class Reports_Visit_Statastics extends AppCompatActivity {

WebView wb;
String ReportsURL, title;
@SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled")
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.visit_statastics_reports);
    wb = (WebView) findViewById(webView);
    wb.getSettings().setLoadsImagesAutomatically(true);
    wb.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    wb.setScrollBarStyle(View.SCROLLBARS_OUTSIDE_OVERLAY);
    Bundle b = getIntent().getExtras();
    ReportsURL = b.getString("URL");
    title = b.getString("title");
    initToolbar();
    wb.setWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient());
    wb.loadUrl(ReportsURL);

}

private class MyWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
    @Override
    public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode,
                                String description, String failingUrl) {
        Log.d("WEB_VIEW_TEST", "error code:" + errorCode + " - " + description);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        // handle different requests for different type of files
        // this example handles downloads requests for .apk and .mp3 files
        // everything else the webview can handle normally
        if (url.endsWith(".pdf")) {
            Uri source = Uri.parse(url);
            // Make a new request pointing to the .apk url
            DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(source);
            // appears the same in Notification bar while downloading
            request.setDescription("Description for the DownloadManager Bar");
            request.setTitle("Document");

                request.allowScanningByMediaScanner();
                request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED);

            // save the file in the "Downloads" folder of SDCARD
            request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS, "Document.doc");
            // get download service and enqueue file
            DownloadManager manager = (DownloadManager) getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
            manager.enqueue(request);
        } else if (url.endsWith(".doc")) {
            Uri source = Uri.parse(url);
            // Make a new request pointing to the .apk url
            DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(source);
            // appears the same in Notification bar while downloading
            request.setDescription("Description for the DownloadManager Bar");
            request.setTitle("Document");

                request.allowScanningByMediaScanner();
                request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED);

            // save the file in the "Downloads" folder of SDCARD
            request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS, "Document.doc");
            // get download service and enqueue file
            DownloadManager manager = (DownloadManager) getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
            manager.enqueue(request);
        } else if (url.endsWith(".xls")) {
            Uri source = Uri.parse(url);
            // Make a new request pointing to the .apk url
            DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(source);
            // appears the same in Notification bar while downloading
            request.setDescription("Description for the DownloadManager Bar");
            request.setTitle("Document");

                request.allowScanningByMediaScanner();
                request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED);

            // save the file in the "Downloads" folder of SDCARD
            request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS, "Document.doc");
            // get download service and enqueue file
            DownloadManager manager = (DownloadManager) getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
            manager.enqueue(request);
        }
        // if there is a link to anything else than .apk or .mp3 load the URL in the webview
        else view.loadUrl(url);
        return true;
    }
}


private void initToolbar() {

    final Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    final ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();

    try {
        if (actionBar != null) {
            actionBar.setTitle(title);
            actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
            actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.d("Doctor_master", e.toString());
    }
}



@Override

public void onBackPressed() {

    super.onBackPressed();
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();

    if (id == android.R.id.home) {
        onBackPressed();
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

}
```

Comment: No Answers Yet!!

Comment: have you tried this solution.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33434532/android-webview-download-files-like-browsers-do

Comment: @Ahamed, thanks for response I just tried it,I have tried contents of questions and contents of accepted answers also but nothing worked!!

Comment: @Akshay Paste the content of html page with buttons. Thanks

Comment: @AnuragSingh Can I send it to you in email, Because it contains clients Info!!

Comment: Sorry. Replace the client's info or other secret info with some @@@@@ tag and then post it here. It may also help other in resolving your problem. Never share or post your client information with anyone :-)

Comment: That page is in Dot net, and hosted by a another web developer, So shall i paste it by inspecting element?

Comment: @AnuragSingh I have updated Code

Comment: @AnuragSingh I am unable to put whole page resource because it extends the size accepted here of Body text in StackOverFlow

Comment: Could you just post the URL of the file that  you are trying to download. Also copy and paste the URL in incognito mode in browser and check if the file downloads.

Comment: It works in incognito  also

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139749/discussion-between-akash-dubey-and-anurag-singh).

Comment: @AkashDubey I cannot download file inside webview which have javascript: doPostBack() called on button click. Can you help out in this.

Comment: @KifayatUllah have u checked for run time permission ?

Comment: @AkashDubey I set the permission "android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE in manifest.

Comment: That is not the solution, many things need to be managed in WebViews, shouldOverrideUrlLoading , and chrome client

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on the comments and discussion from the chat.

I have noticed that `shouldOverrideUrlLoading` is not being called. As, per the android documentation **shouldOverrideUrlLoading**

> Give the host application a chance to take over the control when a new
>   url is about to be loaded in the current `WebView`

But in your case since url doesn't change in `WebView` address bar while clicking any of the three links. It just call javascript code `javascript:__doPostBack('lnkPDF','')`, which calls the post method to generate the file. If you to want use `DownloadManager` to download file while showing notification in notification area, you need to create dynamic static url for files like http:// or https://. E.g. http://www.somedomain/may_be_session_id/some_random_file_number_valid_for_some_time_only/file_name.pdf.

In addition to the above, let the web page change or redirect to new url, only then you will be able to capture urls in `shouldOverrideUrlLoading`.

Try changing your implementation of return in `shouldOverrideUrlLoading` to True if the host application wants to leave the current `WebView` and handle the url itself, otherwise return false.

Comment: unable to download e-statement from icici bank on my webview, it gives link with .jsp but "shouldOverrideUrlLoading" never get called and even download does not start

Comment: .jsp means they are calling java script function, no URL redirection is happening hence shouldOverrideUrlLoading will not be called

Comment: in my case pdf is being downloaded from browser but it never start when we click from webview.. even i redirected to browser again download never started after navigating via webview